# How to use google-services.json and Google Maps API key?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-play-services

An app uses Firebase and Google Maps Android SDK.

Firebase works fine by using the `google-services.json` file downloaded on the Firebase console.

However the Google Maps API key is provided in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value="${google_maps_key}" />
```

while the google maps key is provided in `build.gradle` according to build variant:

```
manifestPlaceholders.google_maps_key = "<REMOVED>";
```

The Google Maps feature works in `debug` build variant but it doesn't work in `release`. The APIs in the Google Cloud Console are enabled and the credentials are correct (SHA1 fingerprints, API restrictions). The Google Cloud console does not show *any* API requests for the release project.

The `google-services.json` contains an API key that I did not find anywhere in the Google Cloud console or Firebase (`"api_key": [{ "current_key": <REMOVED> }]`).

Is is possible that JSON file conflicts with the Google Maps API key?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following, note that google_api_key will be automatically generated with `google-services.json` if you use google-play gradle plugin (i.e. `id("com.google.gms.google-services")`)

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
```

Comment: what if your API key used for maps and the one in google.json are different?

Comment: If they're different then just inject a separate item via a Gradle property?

android.productFlavors.<flavor>.resValue 'string', 'google_maps_api_key', getProperty('GOOGLE_API_KEY_<DEV|PROD>')